# Newbie schema question - coming from the world of relational data structures/SQL

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm coming from a world of SQL and relational data structures and I am struggling a bit to get my head around this different way of structuring data. How should I go about the following but in the DynamoDB world and trying to get every thing in one query? Or am I trying to do the impossible in one query?

---

**Relational/SQL schema**

Table: line

| id | name | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| north-line | North | #0000ff |
| east-line | East | #00ff00 |

Table: status

| id | lineId | code | createdAt | current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc-123-efg | north-line | 2 | 2022-05-10T12:34:42Z | true |
| hij-456-klm | north-line | 10 | 2022-05-10T01:02:02Z | false |
| nop-789-qrs | east-line | 10 | 2022-05-10T12:34:42Z | true |

Foreign key: `status.lineId` -> `line.id`

---

**Queries I need to run**

1. Return all `status` items where `current=true` and also return the `name` and `color` for `line`.
2. Return all `status` items for a given `lineId` and also return the `name` and `color` for `line`.

---

**How far I have got**

| PK | SK | name | color | code | current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| line | north-line#details | North | #0000ff |  |  |
| line | east-line#details | East | #00ff00 |  |  |
| line | north-line#status#2022-05-10T12:34:42Z |  |  | 2 | true |
| line | north-line#status#2022-05-10T01:02:02Z |  |  | 10 |  |
| line | east-line#status#2022-05-10T12:34:42Z |  |  | 10 | true |

Query 1 ❌

I have set up an a global secondary index for `current` so I can get just the current statuses but that does not include the line details (name and color).

Query 2 ✅

Fine here. I can just do a query with `PK=line` and `SK begins with north-line`, for example. I get details (line name and color) and all statuses for that line returned.

---

I've searched and read all sorts but it just isn't clicking. Please don't mark as 'duplicate' but instead try and help the penny drop for me please.

(Or tell me DynamoDB/NoSQL is just the wrong thing for this (I am just trying to learn about something new!) and I should go back to a relational database for this project!)

Comment: Why the phobia to do a second get-item or batch-get-items to retrieve the line details? Also note that designs at small scale and designs at massive scale can be different. What works for 10,000 items doesn't work for 10 trillion.

Comment: @hunterhacker If I had for example 20 different lines returned in current result, then there would 20 more queries as a 2nd call once I know which lines I need. Doesn't seem in the spirit of the DynamoDB way of things? Or am I misinterpreting? I suppose I could get all detail entries in one 2nd call but seems wasteful if I only needed a small fraction of them?

Comment: You can pull those 20 items with a single batch-get-items. The alternative is you denormalize and embed the outer metadata into each individual item. The right choice depends on the scale and speed requirements (denormalization is faster, but takes more space), plus the update frequency for the data being denormalized (need to update across every place it was denormalized).